# Refactoring For-Loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, control-flow

I am currently working on an iTunes data program that's cycling constantly through a user's library to get statistics about one's library.
returns
I have a few code snippets like these:

```
def numArtist(self):
    num = 0
    for song in self.allSongs:
        tempList = []
        if song.artist not in tempList:
            tempList.append(song.artist)
            num += 1
    return num

def getAlbumNames(self):
    albums = []
    for song in self.allSongs:
        if song.album not in albums:
            albums.append(song.album)
    return albums
```

Where the main for loop body is repeated:

```
  for song in self.allSongs: # same for-loop condition
       # different for-loop body
```

Is there a way to refactor methods like these, where I have the same for loop conditions but with different body definitions?

I have a quite a few methods with the same for-loop, so I'd like to find a way to decrease the complexity and redundancy of my code.

---

Just for reference, all Song objects have attributes - artist, album (name),genre, etc - that I'm using to get my data.

Comment: You have a bug in `numArtist`: it reassigns `[]` to `tempList` on each song. Also, you should be using a `set`, not a `list`, since the order of artists doesn't matter. Finally, `len(tempList)` will count the number of items in `tempList` so you don't have to keep track of `num`.

Comment: You can check-out my answer below. In my opinion all of the answers with list comprehensions are wrong, because they work exactly as your for-loops, but are written as comprehensions.

Comment: @Nf4r - your solution also uses a `for` loop to iterate over `allSongs`.  How is that fundamentally different than the other answers?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? I'm not creating extra code to generate the data, like others do. I have single for loop that can be used to generate different data, based on given `attr_name`, without a need to copy-paste the code anywhere else, like others do. I think it's pretty easy to see, that I've created one, simple generator function that is being used to produce values, while the others are just copy-paste the code to change the attribute name in list comp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [set comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and `len` to simplify each of them:

```
def numArtist(self):
    return len({song.artist for song in self.allSongs})

def getAlbumNames(self):
    return {song.album for song in self.allSongs}
```

To make it more generic, you could write a method that takes a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and use that to filter the property out of each song:

```
def uniqueProps(self, fxn):
    return {fxn(song) for song in self.allSongs}

def getAlbumNames(self):
    return self.uniqueProps(lambda song: song.album)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use set comprehensions for both snippets, if that counts as a valid "For-Loop refactoring":

```
artist_count = len({song.artist for song in self.allSongs})

album_names = set({song.album for song in self.allSongs})
```

---

**Generic version using `getattr`**

```
get_values = lambda objs, attr: {getattr(obj, attr) for obj in objs

attributes = 'artist', 'album'
values = [get_values(self.allSongs, name) for name in attributes]

artists, albums = values
artist_count = len(artists)
```

---

**Generic version using `lambda`**

```
get_artist = lambda song: song.artist
get_album = lambda song: song.album

getters = get_artist, get_album

values = [
    {func(song) for song in self.allSongs}
    for getter in getters
]

artists, albums = values
artist_count = len(artists)
```

---

**Generic version using `property`**

```
# If `song` is an instance of the `Song` class and both `artist` and 
# `album` are properties defined on the class, it's also possible to
# directly use the property getter (`property.fget`) to avoid defining
# the lambdas manually:

get_artist = Song.artist.fget
get_album = Song.album.fget

... # <same as above>
```

Comment: I've never seen that `fget` before. That's really handy to know about.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of your `allSongs` list are immutable - which I suspect they are - you can convert your `list`s to `set`s and back to `list`s again - or use set comprehension - to get rid of duplicates.  Then your functions can be greatly simplified like so:

```
def numArtist(self):
    return len({song.artist for sing in self.allSongs})

def getAlbumNames(self):
    return list({song.album for song in self.allSongs})
```

If you're not sure if the `song` objects are mutable or not, try this out anyway.  If they're mutable objects you'll get an exception like:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: ...
```

Comment: Edited to match expected behavior - thanks.  I often use `immutable` as a synonym for `hashable`, which I suppose you could argue isn't exactly accurate.

Comment: @pistache I'm not quite sure it implies hashability, since non-hashable objects can be in lists...unless I'm missing something else.  And I agree that converting to a `list` is unnecessary in the second example, I just wanted to match OPs methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create the generators, that produces the value of song attributes. Let me give you an example:

```
def gen_attr(songs, attr_name):
  for song in songs:
    yield getattr(song, attr_name)

class Song(object):
  def __init__(self, name, artist):
    self.name = name
    self.artist = artist

class Album(object):
  def __init__(self, songs_list):
    self.songs_list = songs_list
  def allSongs(self):
    return self.songs_list

s = Song('Ahoy', 'Pirate')
s1 = Song('Bye', 'My Son')
s2 = Song('Ahoy', 'Captain')

a = Album([s, s1])
```

Now if you want to get all of the song names, u can use:

```
song_names = list(gen_attr(a.allSongs(), 'name'))
print(song_names) # ['Ahoy', 'Bye', 'Ahoy']
```

For non-repeated song names you would use:

```
song_names = list(set(gen_attr(a.allSongs(), 'name')))
print(song_names) # ['Ahoy', 'Bye']
```

To count the non-repeated artists names, you would use:

```
artists = len(set(gen_attr(a.allSongs(), 'artist')))
```

And to create the list of artists, just go for:

```
artists = list(gen_attr(a.allSongs(), 'artist'))
print(artists) # ['Pirate', 'My Son', 'Captain']
```